# Strange behaviors after calling setNotifyValue on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a working application developed on Android that communicates with this BLE device that we have and I'm porting it to iOS. The device has only one characteristic that I'm interested in listening to. I can successfully connect, discover the desired service and characteristic. After I discover the characteristic, this is what I do:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    print("Entered characteristics")
    guard error != nil else {
        for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
            if characteristic.uuid == bufferCharUUID {
                print(characteristic)
                notifyCharacteristic = characteristic
                bluetoothDevice.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                bluetoothDevice.writeValue(Data(bytes: getURI()), for: notifyCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
            }
        }
        return
    }
    print("Error in discovering Characteristics. Error : \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

In Android this makes the device retrieve an URI and write it to the characteristic, but I never even receive the `didUpdateNotificationStateFor`callback, much less the `didUpdateValueFor`. I also never receive the `didWriteValueFor`callback, while, if I never set the notify value, I will receive it.

Other things that happen is that after calling `setNotifyValue` I get an error whenever I call `read​Value(for:​)` or `discover​Descriptors(for:​)` for that characteristic. (If I never setNotify, when I try to read the characteristic's values, it just returns me the bytes that I've written)

The error message is the following: **"The specified UUID is not allowed for this operation."**

For information, in Android we set the characteristicNotification value to true, then we write BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE to the descriptor, but as far as I know, this is automatically done by the CoreBluetooth framework, so I just need to set notification to true.

I cannot even begin to understand where the error resides, if it's a device compatibility issue, if it's something that I'm doing wrong on Swift. I really need a direction so I can begin working on fixing this issue.

Comment: just a note: i think you use guard the wrong way. guard should be used to check values at begin and to have early exit points from the function to avoid to much `if else` statements and make code more readable. in your case you should refactor that the error message should be in the `guard else` block...

Comment: Are you setting the peripheral's delegate property?

Comment: What is the value of the characteristic's `properties` property?

Comment: @Mark Yeah, I receive all the other callbacks, except the didUpdateNotificationState.

Comment: @Paulw11 It's 62 (00111110) so all the notify/indication properties are set.